# JQuery datepicker min date not changing when using JavaScript setInterval()

Tags: javascript, jquery, date, datepicker, setinterval

So I need to change my datepicker's min date to +2 days from today, instead of one day. However I need to change it at say, specifically 4pm every day. The script is running every 10 seconds, so the scenario should be something like this. 15:59:50, min date that can be chosen is tomorrow, 16:00:00 the min date that can be chosen is the day after tomorrow.

Here is my code:

```
    var date1 = new Date();
                    date1.setHours(16,00,0,0);

         $( ".datepicker" ).datepicker({dateFormat: 'yy-mm-dd', minDate:1});

            window.setInterval(function(){
                 var now = new Date();
                if(now.getTime() >= date1.getTime()){
                alert("Greater or equal to");
                $( ".datepicker" ).datepicker({dateFormat: 'yy-mm-dd', minDate:2});
                }
            }, 10000);
```

So when the current time is actually greater or equal to 16:00:00, the alert starts to show up every 10 seconds, but the datepicker min date does not change. Also, if I refresh the page, then the min date changes to +2 days from today. Can anyone please explain why this is happening?

Answer (score 1):

try using this method instead

```
$('.datepicker').datepicker('option', 'minDate', 2);
```

Comment: It worked, thank you! Do you know why it was not working?

Comment: great, happy to help

Comment: "*Do you know why it was not working?*" - Because when you call `datepicker({options})` it creates a new datepicker, but your second call there's already a datepicker so nothing for it to create - it does not update with `{options}`.  You need to use the syntax in this answer to set options on an already existing datepicker.